# Local JS Script, SRC Not Referencing Properly

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, src

I have some simple JS code that stores data about people, and reads/writes this data to Firebase (server back-end). I think the code is fine, but I can't access them from my "index.html" file. Here is my "index.html" file:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.12.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.12.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/firebase.js , ./js/person.js">
  var bob = new Person("Bob");
  var alice = new Person("Alice");

  bob.addPersonToEat(alice);
  alice.addPersonToEat(bob);

  var firebaseUsers = new Firebase("https://web-of-hunger.firebaseio.com/users");

  addNewPerson(firebaseUsers, bob);
</script>
```

Here are my JS files:

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.data = {
    name : name,
    node : {
      id : "empty",
      label : name
    },
    edges : [],
    wantsToEat : [],
    wantsToBeEatenBy : []
  };
};

Person.prototype.addPersonToEat = function(person) {
  this.data.wantsToEat.push(person);
  person.data.wantsToBeEatenBy.push(this);

  this.data.edges.push(
    {from:this.data.node.id, to:person.data.node.id, arrows:'to'}
  );
};

Person.prototype.removePersonToEat = function(person) {
  this.data.wantsToEat.pop(person);
  person.data.wantsToBeEatenBy.pop(this);

  this.data.edges.pop(
    {from:this.data.node.id, to:person.data.node.id, arrows:'to'}
  );
};
```

And the other one:

```
var addNewPerson = function(usersRef, person) {
  if(!checkIfUserExists(person.data.node.id, usersRef)) {
    var newUser = usersRef.push();
    person.data.node.id = newUser.key();
    newUser.set(person.data);
  }
};

var updatePersonData = function(usersRef, person) {
  if(checkIfUserExists(person.data.node.id, usersRef)) {
    usersRef.child(person.data.node.id).update(person.data);
  }
};

var getPersonData = function(usersRef, person) {
  if(checkIfUserExists(person.data.node.id), usersRef) {
    usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      return snapshot.val();
    }, function(errorObject) {
      console.log("read failed");
      return null;
    });
  }
};

var checkIfUserExists = function(userId, usersRef) {
  usersRef.child(userId).once("value", function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.val() != null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

I think the problem is that my script SRC reference is messed up. I did a lot of research and stuff, and I tried every solution. However, my thing just doesn't want to work. I've never had this happen to me before.

Folder structure:

- src

  - index.html
  - js

    - person.js
    - firebase.js

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a `<script>` tag that has both a `src` attribute and script text.  You must use separate script tags for each.  As far as I know, you also can't put multiple URLs in the `src` attribute either.  So, this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/firebase.js , ./js/person.js">
  var bob = new Person("Bob");
  ...
</script>
```

Needs to be broken into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/person.js"></script>
<script>
  var bob = new Person("Bob");
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: @jonathanhuo11 - Did this answer your question?